# unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'

Tags: python, pandas

Both of the below statements are working fine:

```
df_train[df_train['pickup_longitude']<-73]
df_train[df_train['pickup_longitude']>73]
```

Not able to run this:

```
df_train = df_train.drop(((df_train[df_train['pickup_longitude']<-73])|(df_train[df_train['pickup_longitude']>73])).index, axis=0)
```

Comment: Could you add the traceback of the error and clarify what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want only the rows where `pickup_longitude` is above `-73` and below `73`. Accordingly, you can do this instead:

```
df_train = df_train[(df_train['pickup_longitude'] > -73) & (df_train['pickup_longitude'] < 73)]
```